# Pixel issue when drawing on images - html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

First of all here my full code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f5z8qtcp/13/

**Reproducing my problem:**

Click in the image and drag your mouse randomly without releasing the right button of your mouse.

You will see that it leave traces on the image !

*How to clear all traces without reloading the image at each time (This will lag my browser for bigger size images) ?*

The idea is to clear the trace at each time we add new rectangle but without reloading image.

I tried with:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

No effect ... and this will remove the rectangles.

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: There is no need to re-load the image, simply redraw the image object. You can also use a secondary canvas element on top, draw+clear the rectangle, when mouse is released use the final region on the main canvas.

Comment: secondary canvas will require to load the same image on it + draw the objects ... image reload is better than this. redrawing the objects do not solve it.

Comment: The second canvas doesn't need anything - it will be transparent so the image will show through.

Comment: I am already redraw them with `drawAll();`

Comment: @K3N How to make that ?

Comment: I just made your idea but do not work, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/f5z8qtcp/14/ when i create a rectangle, automatically i show a transparent canvas on it and then hide it ... this make no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing on image while mouse moving, you can't in simple way undo it, when someone for example make smaller his selection. The fastest way to fix it is just using some `div` over image. After mouse release - then remove div and draw on image final selection.

Comment: I didn't understood your approch, can you develop please ?

Comment: I just made your idea but do not work, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/f5z8qtcp/14/ when i create a rectangle, automatically i show a transparent canvas on it and then hide it ... this make no effect.